# How does the ReactJS create unique id for each element when we use id selector with css modules

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I am using SCSS modules with ReactJs and I have used id as the css selector like below.

**In component** (Name of the component :- PrayerRequestDropDown)

```
import styles from './PrayerRequestDropDown.module.scss';
import cx from 'classnames';

<InputField
 {...props}
 name="answer"
 id={cx(styles.addAnswer)}
 type="textarea"
 placeholder="type your answer"
/>
```

**In SCSS file**

```
#addAnswer {
  min-width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  height: 8rem;
  border: 1px solid $medium-gray;
}
```

I need to caputure this input field in otder to run automation test on it. So i inspect the code in order to see the Id attribute of this element. It shows like this.

[image]

When I check it after the deployment also seems to be same id. **can anyone explain how does react create this id and is that change time to time?**

Answer (score 1):

React itself doesn't do anything with IDs or your styles encapsulation.

You are using CSS Modules, which are namespacing classes, so they don't have global scope when you import them.

Please refer to [CSS Modules documentation](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)

You probably want to use `:global` to make ID globally available, but please consider *not* styling by ID if possible

Your solution doesn't work, because you are passing a hashed classname value into ID, instead static string value

Comment: I just need to know this id is changing from time to time or not?  and how does this create? @Łukasz

Comment: Do you use create-react-app?

Comment: You are doing `id={cx(styles.addAnswer)}` instead of `id="addAnswer "`. So you are putting dynamic, random-hashed class (`styles.addAnswer` is dynamically computed because this is the core concept of css modules). If you want id to be static, just use it as a string.